# Closedness of the range of differential operator first order

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

The fact that the range of gradient from $H_0^1$ to $L_2$ is closed is well known. In general we can define some kind of weak derivative in the form
\begin{equation}
Du=\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}\partial_i u_j
\end{equation}
using an analogous definition to the definition of weak derivative related to Sobolev space, where $a_{ij}$ are constants. Also, we can define a Hilbert space $V$ as the closure of $C_0^\infty$ by the norm $|u|=|u|_{L_2}+|Du|_{L_2}$. Then my question is, is the range of $D:V\rightarrow L_2$ in general closed in $L_2$ or is there a counter example?

Comment: Would the functions in your closure have weak derivatives? What do you think? If so, in what space would that put those functions?

Comment: @TrialAndError The functions in $L_2$ don't need to have weak derivatives, but one can define a space of functions in $L_2$ which have those weak derivatives in distributional sense and in $L_2$, and the space of such functions equipped with the norm above is a Hilbert space. One can also prove that the smooth functions always have those weak derivatives which coincide with the classical derivatives. Therefore we can define the space $V$ as closure by the special norm. But now the set of all weak derivatives is subset of $L_2$, and it is not known if this subset is closed in $L_2$.